# emacs -nw standard input is not a tty on ConEmu and Mintty

Tags: microsoft-windows, terminal-emacs

On my Windows XP machine I use Emacs-25.2.1. During web app development I use **[ConEmu version 191012](https://conemu.github.io)** and I need to use Emacs at the command line. When I enter `emacs -nw` on **ConEmu**, it says

```
emacs: standard input is not a tty
```

This error occurs on **MSYS2**'s default terminal **Mintty** which is invoked by `cmd.exe /A /Q /K C:\msys32\mingw32_shell.bat`, too but it doesn't occur on Windows' default **CMD.exe** and **PowerShell** so I guess it may have something to do with the Environment Variables. Several months ago, the ConEmu had a problem where the arrow keys and backspace were not working, (roughly described [here](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1124)) and I remember fixing it by changing or deleting an environment variable. This `standard input is not a tty` problem seemed to pop up roughly around the same after I fixed that problem but I'm not 100% sure of this.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the erroneous startup script of ConEmu named `Bash::Msys2-32` which was confusing the `emacs -nw` It was (the erroneous one)

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & set "PATH=%ConEmuDrive%\msys32\usr\bin;%PATH%" 
& %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-32.exe 
-new_console:p %ConEmuDrive%\msys32\usr\bin\bash.exe
 --login -i 
-new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\msys32\msys2.ico"
```

It should have been like (the correct one)

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\msys32\usr\bin\bash.exe 
--login -i -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\msys32\msys2.ico" 
-new_console:d:"C:\Documents and Settings\lenovo"
```